# Gcloud App Deploy on Google Cloud Console: Says I'm missing Gem Railties even though I've included it in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-app-engine, rubygems, gcloud

I'm running into the following error when trying to deploy an test application on Google's App Engine, although I believe railties is already included in my Gemfile:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-06-11T22:43:27.023Z13706.vt.2: bundler: failed to load command: rails (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rails)
Gem::Exception: can't find executable rails for gem railties. railties is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
  /opt/rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:374:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /opt/rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:402:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server Puma -p $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby

env_variables:
    SECRET_KEY_BASE: b13409e869eb538c5b2ae943540f9e210373d2e48ff3f4c5b03d8a0d6164bdc4060544c0bee6dcf6b192c41e6e22c10c843363c7728abd1bf366945a17e074d3

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: web3careers-88177:us-central1:postgres-instance
```

and the beginning of my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.7.6"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

gem "pg"

gem "rack"
```

When I change the entrypoint to using Rackup, it tells me I'm missing the rack gem, although it's already installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm also seeing this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This isn't *really* a solution. However, for anyone that sees this you can remove `env: flex` from the `app.yaml` and it should work. Why I'm not sure.